Django-redis configuration
I have a Django app. I want to use django-redis to cache the results of my queries so as to improve the app performance. I've implemented this on the local server and it works as intended. When deployed on a live server, I get an Internal Server Error. This is because of the configurations of Redis to the app which forms the basis of my question. How should I go about configuring my app with Redis. I'm deploying using AWS.
Below are the cache settings in settings.py
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient"
        },
        "KEY_PREFIX": "example"
    }
}```


I would start by going to the server logs and getting the actual error message, which could give you some clue as to what is incorrect in your configuration. An Internal Server Error is just a message from the server to the client (web browser) that something went wrong. You should always go to the server logs when you get that to  see what the actual error is, and include the actual error message in your questions here on Stack Overflow.
